# As programmers say: Strive to be lazy

Tags: code-golf, string

### Story

Have you seen [this](https://9gag.com/gag/aE2y7MO) post from [9gag](https://9gag.com/)?
Maybe you got the feeling to make your own sentences. But then you realize that you could just golf a script in half an hour, and you will never have to deal time with that.

### The submission

Your program will get an input string which it will return with added quotation marks as explained below.
Standard loopholes are forbidden. Output as a list of lines is allowed. Trailing spaces and empty lines that don't break the output are allowed.

### The rules of input

- The input only contains printable ASCII characters.
- The input may contain spaces. The words are determined with them.
- It's guaranteed that a space will never be followed by another space.
- The case of no input or empty string doesn't matter.

### The rules of output

If one word is given then the program has to return the string between quotation marks.

If the input string has 2 or more words, it first returns the initial input, but the first word is in quotation marks. Then on the next line, it returns the initial input, but with the second word in quotes. And so on for the remaining words.

In general, the program has to return as many lines as there are words in the input.

### Examples:

```
test -> "test"

This is codegolf -> "This" is codegolf
                    This "is" codegolf
                    This is "codegolf"

This is a significantly longer, but not the longest testcase -> "This" is a significantly longer, but not the longest testcase
                                                                This "is" a significantly longer, but not the longest testcase
                                                                This is "a" significantly longer, but not the longest testcase
                                                                This is a "significantly" longer, but not the longest testcase
                                                                This is a significantly "longer," but not the longest testcase
                                                                This is a significantly longer, "but" not the longest testcase
                                                                This is a significantly longer, but "not" the longest testcase
                                                                This is a significantly longer, but not "the" longest testcase
                                                                This is a significantly longer, but not the "longest" testcase
                                                                This is a significantly longer, but not the longest "testcase"

Here is an another one -> "Here" is an another one
                          Here "is" an another one
                          Here is "an" another one
                          Here is an "another" one
                          Here is an another "one"
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the least byte answer wins!

Comment: Will there be duplicate words?

Comment: Can we assume the input string will not contain `"` characters?

Comment: Re *"Strive to be lazy"*: I think this is a misrepresentation of what Larry Wall said. - *"[Most folks see laziness as a synonym for slacker or couch potato, but Wall's definition is about efficiency.](https://searchcio.techtarget.com/tip/Embracing-Perl-creator-Larry-Walls-programmer-vices-as-IT-virtues)"*

Comment: This "problem" should be "fun" to "golf".

Comment: Can we use different quotes, like `''`, `‘’`, or `“”`, rather than `""`?

Answer (score 10):

### vim, 38 bytes

```
:s/"/<C-d>/g
qqysW"Ypds"W@qq@qdk:%s/<C-d>/"/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/36pYX0nfxlk3xU4/nauwsLI4XCmyIKVYKdyhsNChMCXbSrUYKq0EVPD/f0lGZrECECUqKJWkFpco/dctAwA)

Requires the [vim-surround plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround).

If the input does not contain `"` characters, this can be done in **19 bytes**:

```
qqysW"Ypds"W@qq@qdk
```

Here, we record a recursive macro (`qq ... @qq@q`) that surrounds a word with quotation marks (`ysW"`), duplicates the line (`Yp`), deletes the quotation marks (`ds"`), and moves to the next word (`W`) before calling itself recursively. After it terminates, there are two extraneous lines, which are deleted with `dk`.

The full solution simply wraps this with `:s/"/<C-d>/g` at the beginning, which replaces existing `"` characters with an unprintable character, and `:%s/<C-d>/"/g` at the end, which undoes the replacement.

Comment: I actually made the examples with the same method :D

Answer (score 8):

### Haskell, 65 bytes

```
([]#).words
a#(b:c)=unwords(a++('"':b++"\""):c):(a++[b])#c
_#_=[]
```

Returns a list of lines.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYyxbsMwDER3fwUhD5HgNB9gwHuHdmo3RzBkhbKFKpQhySj681WZeCpwIB@Ph1tN/sIQqoMBrlWOulWX75huuTGtnHurhp2etzRdJ0/i1M9dJ65CKP71D3OctWptM7XTMOp6N5646m629wnksba9fJT0RnAByXkhtGJ0CsYGQBTMRZwf9Ln6DCwbb7jE4P67BrJfyDtvDZXwAyHSgukM816AYoGy4uFlZh7WZDwaXjHhs4FYkXMJIqHQ9de6YJZcX@y2/QE)

Comment: This seems to fail when the input contains quotation marks, newlines or other escaped charcters.

Comment: [It doesn't fix the issue but you could save a byte by removing the tail call optimization](https://tio.run/##VYzBjsIwDETv/Qorp0Sw/QCk3jnsnnZvpUJpcNJog1PFqRA/TzH0hGR5nsbjmSz/Y0qrhw5O69XOsNAtlwu3oX1rE7Q9jKbTPOUbvPAgKfGMDjCaJvRD1w/yGUkq5PRzBr3JvNTfWr4JWtC7Xa/UYAS9gb4BUBW5qv2L/qbIIHNSLl8w5OQ/fQscA0UfnaWa7pAyBSx7GJcKlCvUCTePhWU5y7g1HLHgu4FksuQKZEI1rA/nkw28frl5fgI "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: @SriotchilismO'Zaic: fixed. Thanks for pointing out. Regarding the shorter version: xnor already posted this as an [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/185443/34531).

Comment: Not quite fixed, since words considers `\n` to be whitespace it behaves inproperly when it is present.

Comment: @SriotchilismO'Zaic: "The input only contains printable ASCII characters", which is Space to `~`. "The input may contain spaces" - not "whitespace".

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>15</s>  14 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Ḳ⁾""j$€⁹¦K¥ⱮJ$
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjk2PGvcpKWWpPGpa86hx56Fl3oeWPtq4zkvl/@H2yP//QzIyixWAKDk/JTU9PycNAA)**

#### How?

```
Ḳ⁾""j$€⁹¦K¥ⱮJ$ - Link: list of characters, S
Ḳ              - split (S) at spaces -> A
             $ - last two links as a monad:
           Ɱ   -   map...
            J  -   ...across: range of length -> I = [1,2,...len(A)]
          ¥    -   ...doing: last two links as a dyad: i.e. f(A, i) for i in I
      € ¦      -     sparse application...
       ⁹       -     ...to indices: chain's right argument, i
     $         -     ...action: last two links as a monad:
 ⁾""           -       literal list of characters = ['"', '"']
    j          -       join (with A[i]) -> (e.g. with ['i','s']) ['"','i','s','"']
         K     -     join with spaces
```

Comment: [Easy save](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjk2PGvcpKWU92rhO5eHO2YeWARleKt6Pmtb8P9we@f9/SEZmsQIQJeenpKbn56QBAA). (Decided to comment here because you were the first to post similar code. :P)

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer thanks, came back to post a similar improvement myself.

Answer (score 7):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 17 bytes

```
 
" $'¶$` "
^|$
"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYtBCkIxDET3OUUoFV14Dz2Aa/m15reBkkATF4Ln@gfwYrUoCMNjeMx0cpY0dofTMhACxv17iwsGuL4ihDGczOFS2XAm652KtvUvEhoX4ZVzEm9PbCqF@hFvD0dRR6/0czb7RE5GcKZO3/NcVOqoQh8) Link includes test suite. Explanation:

```
 
" $'¶$` "
```

Expand each space by duplicating the line and then inserting quotation marks.

```
^|$
"
```

Fix the first and last lines.

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>43 42 41</s>  38 bytes

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to @mazzy*

Uses the non-standard but widely supported [`RegExp.left​Context`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/leftContext) and [`RegExp.rightContext`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/rightContext). That's a lot of different quotes...

```javascript
s=>s.replace(/(\S+) ?/g,`$\`"$1" $'
`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYxBCsIwEEX3PcUQAiZYWzxA9RC67KIxTtJIyJRMFDx9DLhzIXw@n8fnPczLsM1hK4dEd6xuqjydeMi4RWNRjWq@7DWcR98vcl6EPAqQu27R1VJiijhE8sopcUUuQuvuF6@BocU2uafo/lwMcPApuGBNKvENkZLH3MPtWSBRgbLil3HbraxhbLr6AQ)

Comment: Smart! But see on the comma in the test case `This is a significantly "longer,"...`

Comment: Wouldn't `/(\S+)/g` work?

Comment: @mazzy Oh, thanks. I actually did it that way on purpose because I misread the test case with a comma. Now fixed.

Comment: @Shaggy I think we need to capture the space so that it doesn't appear in the left context of the next word.

Comment: (@Shaggy But your comment brought to light that I forgot to remove the `/i`. Thanks!)

Comment: The code appends tail empty line. Why not add an extra space to the last line? `s.replace(/(\S+) ?/g,$\"$1" $'`

Comment: @mazzy I guess that's fine indeed. Thanks!

Comment: The only problem with [using just `/\S+/g`](https://tio.run/##fYxBCsIwEEX3PUUIQRus7QnqJeqyi4xxkkZCpmSi4OljwJ0L4fP5PD7vAS9gm8NezonuWN1ceb7wmHGPYLGf1uU0@cGo1Uh1kOrYGV0tJaaIYyTfu15ekYvUuvvFW2DRYpvXU3R/LiA4@BRcsJBKfItIyWMexO1ZRKIiyoZfxm23ssDYdPUD) is that it adds a leading space to all but the first line. It's been asked in the comments whether that's allowed.

Answer (score 6):

## Java, <s>235 183</s> 132 bytes

```java
s->{String a[]=s.split(" "),r="",t;for(int l=a.length,i=0,j;i<l;i++,r+="\n")for(j=0;j<l;)r+=(t=i==j?"\"":"")+a[j++]+t+" ";return r;}
```

-52 bytes by abusing a variety of things (static access, list vs array, print instead of returning, etc. Thanks @ValueInk!)
-51 bytes by beung lazy and letting @KevinCruijssen do the work for me 

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##NY4xa8MwEIV3/4rjJgk5JnNUtVu2TunmeFBtyZGqyEY6B4Lxb3dVSOHgHY/v3j2vH/rgh5@9Dzpn@NQurpWLZJLVvYHzeqHk4giWvZbM5VbNy3dwPWTSVOQxuQHu5fLFtB3oNGa@VmewoPZ8eP@P0W2ncpPn4IghIK@TQqxJ2imx8hWC0k0wcaRb7dSx9tK9BemEqJNQeI3I/0CvjtIXnxeTkXJK@Q@8Ip4QudCtF6ITJEq8TIaWFCHJbZfV5ZnJ3JtpoWYuZShEZhvL8OvmMpTpp8GMU7DIuay2bf8F)

Comment: That's some crazy overhead you need for the `java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange`. If you utilize `java.util.List` you can use `subList` for shorter, and print to STDOUT instead of building an array. [I got 193 bytes with those ideas, and also abusing the var keyword.](https://tio.run/##dY5Bb4MwDIXv/Aorp0TQqHfGpF162k7dbd3BBcJMA0FxQOoQv51ZVa@TLFmy33vf63HBQ9/c9tojM3wgjWtGY2qjw7qF07oEasDpc4o0dsCm3LJpvnqqgRMmWQ/BIL6n5usbMHZs1uwEDqqdD6/rghGw6oVl50TevsWId7bI78RJs@XJU9IKlDGlC1FLAaDqWPgKLdNvq01JL7405zundrBhTnYSVvKjflJtH6SBJBTimK@P3GNBxuQKLkrlaLs2acpzOVxElv9vo8IbY6z8By19tr3MnHVaff4Qg0wdmrYL3ilTZtu2/wE)

Comment: @ValueInk thanks! I also replaced `String.join` with `s.join` for those extra IDE warnings (and -10 bytes).

Comment: [132 bytes](https://tio.run/##NY4xa8MwEIV3/4rjJgk5JnNUtVu2TunmeFBtyZGqyEY6B4Lxb3dVSOHgHY/v3j2vH/rgh5@9Dzpn@NQurpWLZJLVvYHzeqHk4giWvZbM5VbNy3dwPWTSVOQxuQHu5fLFtB3oNGa@VmewoPZ8eP@P0W2ncpPn4IghIK@TQqxJ2imx8hWC0k0wcaRb7dSx9tK9BemEqJNQeI3I/0CvjtIXnxeTkXJK@Q@8Ip4QudCtF6ITJEq8TIaWFCHJbZfV5ZnJ3JtpoWYuZShEZhvL8OvmMpTpp8GMU7DIuay2bf8F)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen thanks

Comment: [Beaten](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/185532/16236) with 117 bytes! Your turn ;)

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire no thank you :^)

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Challenge accepted and beaten, sir! ;p [71 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/185575/52210)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Nice! I haven't even thought regex would do the job. Well done ;-)

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Yeah, at first I wasn't sure it was possible. Took a bit of fiddling around with the positive look-behind and look-ahead before I got it to work, which was both annoying and fun to do (and kind of distracting from my actual job-work, haha xD). And the 71 byte version wasn't too efficient I now notice, since I'm now at 62 bytes. :)

Answer (score 5):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) with `-an`, 53 bytes

The flags `-an` are read each line and split to `$F`.

```ruby
$F.size.times{|i|a=$F.dup;a[i]=?"+a[i]+?";puts a*' '}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYvdCoJQEITvfYpFAiHLFxDxLnqA7qKLo666YLvi7rmwn1fvdCoIhpnhY2bxzRrC5lAo3bAwuqLeH/RwVUSdn0t3pktVp/kn8zotZ28KbptB9gzBUC05jaQQ1UqHg0z9HzhQGph6ah3btMIkPOCyg8YbsBjYiD@msUdrnWJyxAW/Z46SOFlAGF8yGwlr2Dt@Aw)

Answer (score 5):

First code golf attempt hopefully it's not terrible and hopefully it's not rule breaking

### Kotlin, <s>105</s> <s>112</s> <s>147</s> 117 bytes/chars

```
fun main(a:Array<String>){val q=a[0].split(" ")
q.forEach{println(q.fold(""){i,n->i+if(it==n)"\"$n\" " else n+" "})}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYtBCsIwEEX3nmIILhLU4lpswYUn0J11MbZNOzhO2iQKUnr2GOEvHo/3ny4ySUr2LfBCEo2Hk/f4PV6iJ@krM3@QYSrxtr8XYWSKWoEyq6mwzp@xGeYxd5FF/w23Wikz01Z2FW3IaoplKUbVai11/kHHoQPZZFzMsqSUrgMFyGtc2/WOLTwoNgNgCD8)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 14 bytes

```
ð¡©ε®y…"ÿ"Nǝ}»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8IZDCw@tPLf10LrKRw3LlA7vV/I7Prf20O7//0syMosVgChRoSS1uAQA)

---

+1 byte (and it works for the edge case) thanks to Emigna.
-1 byte thanks to Kevin!

Comment: Unfortunately you need to use `ð¡` to handle input such as `test`.

Comment: [-1 byte by using a map and `»`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8IZDCw@tPLf10LrKRw3LlA7vV/I7Prf20O7//0syMosVgChRoSS1uAQA).

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript, <s>91</s> <s>97</s> <s>75</s> 78 bytes

```js
f= 

t=>t.split` `.map((c,i,a)=>[...a.slice(0,i),`"${c}"`,...a.slice(i+1)].join` `)

// and test
console.log(f("Hello folks and world").join('\n'));
```

Outputs a list of lines as a JavaScript array. The last entry has a trailing space as allowed in the question. The test code writes each entry to the console on a separate line for demonstration purposes.

Thanks to Shaggy for 19 bytes off and no leading spaces - when the spread operator is used on an empty array to initialize an array literal, no slots are created in the array produced by the spread operator:

```
let empty = [];
let array = [...empty, value]
//  produces an array of length 1 containing value
```

<sub>(The 91 byte version had a leading space on the first line, the 97 byte version took 6 bytes to remove it.)</sub>

Comment: [78 bytes](https://tio.run/##TctBCsIwEEDRvacIQWgG41TX0q69gwoJaSqjY6Y0QRfi2aN05fr/d/NPn8NMU9kmGWIdu1q6vmCemIpTDh9@MiZYsh66/oSIHjNTiGZnCazT63f4aGf/Am32cMGbUPp5qG2rfBpUibmsgqQsHJHlakajj5FZ1Ch8z8vzkpkHDYs1zTk1AIf6BQ)

Comment: The snippet doesn't run because you defined the `f` function. Otherwise verified. Good job!

Comment: @krinistof fixed it, thx!

Comment: Words after the quoted word are separated by commas instead of spaces (Firefox, not sure if that's a browser issue)

Comment: @wastl Golfed 3 bytes too many and didn't see the commas due to blurry eyes. Putting back the second spread operator (as in Shaggy"s link) removes the commas . Note to self... put my glasses on next time ;-(

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>79</strike>, <strike>69</strike>, 65 bytes

```python
w,i=input(),0
while~i:m=w.split();m[i]='"%s"'%m[i];print(*m);i+=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v1wn0zYzr6C0RENTx4CrPCMzJ7Uu0yrXtlyvuCAnEyhqnRudGWurrqRarKSuCmJbFxRl5pVoaOVqWmdq2xr@/2@oYKRgrGCiYAoA)

Shaved 10 bytes thanks to xnor. And now this is 65 bytes as per  Erik the Outgolfer solution. Program ends with IndexError but this is fine.

Comment: Terminating with error [is fine for programs](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4781/20260). A handy trick: you can use `print(*l)` in Python 3 in place of `print(" ".join(l))`.

Comment: Even better, use [Extended Iterable Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/).

Comment: [65 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v1wn0zYzr6C0RENTx4CrPCMzJ7Uu0yrXtlyvuCAnEyhqnRudGWurrqRarKSuCmJbFxRl5pVoaOVqWmdq2xr@/2@oYKRgrGCiYAoA): Instead of assigning `w` to `input().split()`, assign it to `input()`, then, in the `while` loop, assign `m` to `w.split()`, which will create a new list at each iteration to avoid reference issues, then set `m[i]` to `'"%s"'%m[i]` and `print(*m)`.

Answer (score 4):

## Java 8, <s>72</s> <s>71</s> <s>67</s> 62 bytes

```java
s->s.replaceAll("(?<=(^.*))(\\S+) ?(?=(.*$))","$1\"$2\" $3\n")
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##dVBNT8MwDL3vV1hRD8k@KgE3xqi4wYFxGDcKUpZmbUbmVI07aUL77SVtgxASkxLLsd97efZeHuViX3x2ykrv4Vka/JoAGCTd7KTSsO6fABtqDJageEy8WIb6eRKCJ0lGwRoQVtD5xb1PG13bQH6wljOe3a34RzoVguf5ZiYg49mKp9NECDZnyVXOkuucQXKTIxPdsles260NilH46EwBh2As/v32DlKMrkh74qyPbPDzU3mtjIdwlCt06ezu/64Eb0o0O6Mkkj2BdVjqZg7blgAdAVV6rHkamEp6/VfpUTd6UArwSjfgMALO4f6uZphgYMTtGaxbijNsTp70IXUtpXVokkXOnvr@LbDZCFxeBL60NCIvYzBVfJSJzs7dNw)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->                    // Method with String as both parameter and return-type
  s.replaceAll("...",  //  Replace all matches in this regex
               "...")  //  With this
                       //  And then return the result
```

*Regex explanation:*

```python
(?<=(^.*))(\\S+) ?(?=(.*$))   # === MATCH ===
(?<=     )                    # A positive look-behind to:
     ^.*                      #  The optional leading portion of the string
    (   )                     #  (which is captured in capture group 1)
           \\S+               # Followed by one or more non-space characters,
                              # so the next word in line
          (    )              # (which is captured in capture group 2)
                 ?            # Followed by an optional space
                  (?=     )   # Followed by a positive look-ahead to:
                      .*$     #  The trailing optional portion of the string
                     (   )    #  (which is captured in capture group 3)

$1\"$2\" $3\n                 # === REPLACEMENT ===
$1                            # The match of capture group 1
                              # (the leading portion)
    $2                        # Followed by the match of capture group 2
                              # (the current word in the 'iteration'),
  \"  \"                      # surrounded by quotation marks
                              # Followed by a space character
         $3                   # Followed by the match of capture group 3
                              # (the trailing portion)
           \n                 # Followed by a trailing newline
```

Comment: You have just paved the way for a multitude of regex answers. Well done.

Comment: I tried to port this to Python. Sometimes I wish regex parsers were consistent across languages.

Comment: @BenjaminUrquhart Unfortunately they aren't.. Java regex is different than C# regex, Python is different again, Perl is different again, etc. Indeed a bit annoying.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/), 98 chars.

First submission ever. This can definitely be shortened. I just wanted to get an answer in quickly.

```
a=->s{s.split.each_index{|i|puts s.split.each_with_index.map{|a,j|i==j ? "\"#{a}\"":a}.join(" ")}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY1BCsJQDET3niJ8NwraAwjVrQdwpyKxjTal/l9@UlTanr1G60ZwMwwzw7zYnJ/DgOlyLa0kUlesCWFWnNjn9Gg77upGBX6qO@u3T25Ytx0uyo7TtIQNuIObttgfnFthn5SB/cyBm/f9gHunJOqOE3NbigQsgIA@aEERgqexep9D3hgtQyW4h5gL/AvH@a6wm8@T8NXzxQZeqydUwV8pLuDcKBgCDDJmYt4kQzHg8AI)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! My suggestion would be for each index, save `s.split` as a variable and edit the index you want to have the quotes around it, instead of using the overly verbose `each_with_index.map`. Also, you can submit the anonymous lambda without naming it, and join can be replaced with a `*` operator. [This drops your byte count to 64 bytes.](https://tio.run/##bY3BDoIwEETvfsWmR1F@gCBXP8AbElNgpU1IId1tkADfXlfx6GV38mYy40M9R53f4/lCC6U09pZT1I15WNfia1ntivmPZ1jaKi9U8vlJobIxMAEeFahti7pUjMSqOoi6okewBBq0G9igh8Hhbk2WDbRBChvNCNPgW4J/cI/fjNR8m8h2zj4l4LifoR9ch/4EdWCQCZCRnZFoOY0mGYxv)

Comment: Fantastic! I knew there was a shorter way to do the join, but I was trying to get out of the office and wanted to submit something before leaving XD. I didn't realize the rules allowed for anonymous lambdas like that.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 64 bytes

```hs
map unwords.g.words
g(h:t)=(('"':h++"\""):t):map(h:)(g t)
g _=[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU/LasQwELvnK4Qva5NtPiCQew/tqb1lw@J6/aKuHewJpT/fdLrppSBGQhKCCbq925R2N132D71iy5@l3trghzt3XoaR1CTlSZzG0PfiIoRiZ@QyR0p6kOo8rtO88EDMmMDR8xXyoHWjF6pPGQNk389CLIqlU5g7QJBtJM6/6jXEBoYpN@tLcv9djRZ9ji4anSl9IZXsbT3jbSPkQqBgD6@x5mN0s8fCo632vpAZhXsVJf9l/MuyfxuXtG/7g1nXHw)

Outputs a list of strings. Based on [nimi's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/185426/20260).

Comment: This answer like nimi's doesn't work properly when the input contains escaped characters like `\n` or `"`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>43</s> 40 bytes

```perl6
{m:ex/^(.*?<<)(\S+)(>>.*)$/>>.join('"')}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJZm@7861yq1Qj9OQ0/L3sZGUyMmWFtTw85OT0tTRR9IZeVn5mmoK6lr1v5P01AKycgsVgCi5PyU1PT8nDQlTaCS4sTK/wA)

Matches all possible words, then joins each list by quotes. This could be one byte shorter if we could output lines in reverse order.

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{                                      }  # Anonymous code block
 m:ex/^                  $/               # Match all strings
       (.*?)         (.*)                 # Match before and after sections
            <<(\S+)>>                     # And the actual word (with no spaces)
                           >>.join('"')   # And join each line by "s
```

Answer (score 3):

### [Reflections](https://gitlab.com/TheWastl/Reflections#reflections), 229 bytes

```
  _1 +\ /\/(3\  /(0\
/+_:   # \#_: v1=2#_ \
\     /_+/:3; / 1/\:1)
/v(3(2/ \3)(3 ;\#@ \ /
   /:#_(0\:_ / (0*  /0  \
 0 >~    <>~   <0 \  *#_/
 \       /     /\/ v/ 
   \=2#_1/\2#_>  (0~
                 \ ^\
\                   /
```

[Test it!](https://thewastl.gitlab.io/Reflections/reflections.html##ICBfMSArXCAvXC8oM1wgIC8oMFwKLytfOiAgICMgXCNfOiB2MT0yI18gXApcICAgICAvXysvOjM7IC8gMS9cOjEpCi92KDMoMi8gXDMpKDMgO1wjQCBcIC8KICAgLzojXygwXDpfIC8gKDAqICAvMCAgXAogMCA+fiAgICA8Pn4gICA8MCBcICAqI18vCiBcICAgICAgIC8gICAgIC9cLyB2LyAKICAgXD0yI18xL1wyI18+ICAoMH4KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICBcIF5cClwgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgL/8w/zIwMP8w/1RoaXMgaXMgYSBzaWduaWZpY2FudGx5IGxvbmdlciwgYnV0IG5vdCB0aGUgbG9uZ2VzdCB0ZXN0Y2FzZQ==)

I "quickly" "golfed" this in a "funny" "golfing" language.

Looking at all that whitespace, it could probably be shorter.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>94</s> 76 bytes

-18 bytes thanks to Giuseppe

```r
m=matrix(s<-scan(,a<-'"'),n<-length(s),n);diag(m)=paste0(a,s,a);write(m,1,n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpNCoAgEEDhq0QbRxih1tktusBgZoI/4Qh1@0l4mw9eE8l7pt7iB2wNOyqAZI2alcZiTfIl9Bt4QG9npABZ7w9x9wsQMpLe3ha7h4zrWOS4I08jV08farpEfg)

Thanks to digEmAll for setting up the TIO properly. It takes in e.g. `This is codegolf` and outputs correctly

```
"This" is codegolf 
 This "is" codegolf 
 This is "codegolf"
```

It uses a matrix format with the sentence repeated `n` times; then we only need to change the diagonal entries. Note that usually, in R code-golf, strings are read in with `scan(,"")`, but any string can be used instead of the empty string as the `what` (or `w`) parameter.

Explanation of old ungolfed version:

```r
s <- scan(t=scan(,''),w=t)    # read in input and separate by spaces
n <- length(s)                # number of words
m = matrix(s, n, n)           # fill a matrix, one word per entry, each column corresponds to the whole sentence. The sentence is repeated n times.
diag(m) = paste0('"', s, '"') # replace diagonal entries with the corresponding word surrounded by quotes
cat(rbind(m,"\n"))        # add a \n at the end of each column, then print column-wise
```

Comment: [76 bytes](https://tio.run/##DcpNCoAgEEDhq0QbRxih1tktusBgZoI/4Qh1@0l4mw9eE8l7pt7iB2wNOyqAZI2alcZiTfIl9Bt4QG9npABZ7w9x9wsQMpLe3ha7h4zrWOS4I08jV08farpEfg)

Comment: @Giuseppe Thanks! How did I not see that I didn't need two calls to `scan`??

Comment: Sometimes you just get into a golfing groove. If we can use other quotes than `""`, we can reduce to [68 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9c2N7GkKLNCo9hGtzg5MU9DR11dUyfPRjcnNS@9JEOjGMjRtE7JTEzXyNW0LQ4szS9JBQpalxdlAhm5OoZA6f8hGZnFCkCUnJ@Smp6fk/b/PwA) using `sQuote`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
▓¼MY@≈╢∞◙╗
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=b2ac4d5940f7b6ec0abb&i=this+is+codegolf&a=1)

Unpacked, ungolfed, and commented, it looks like this.

```
jY      split on spaces and store in y register
m       for each word, run the rest of the program and implicitly output
  '"|S  surround with double quotes
  yia&  start with register y, and replace the ith element, where i is the iteration index
  J     join with spaces
```

[Run this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=jY++++%09split+on+spaces+and+store+in+y+register%0Am+++++%09for+each+word,+run+the+rest+of+the+program+and+implicitly+output%0A++%27%22%7CS%09surround+with+double+quotes%0A++yia%26%09start+with+register+y,+and+replace+the+ith+element,+where+i+is+the+iteration+index%0A++J+++%09join+with+spaces&i=this+is+codegolf)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 62 bytes

Thanks @Shaggy for golfing off 10 bytes

```js
f=
x=>x.split` `.map((c,i,a)=>(s=[...a],s[i]=`"${c}"`,s.join` `))

console.log(f("Hello folks and world").join('\n'));
```

#### Explanation

- The function splits the string at each space (x.split` `)
- For each element in the resulting array perform the following function
- Create a shallow copy of the array (s=[...a])
- Replace the nth element in the array with itself surrounded with quotation marks (s[i]=`"${c}"`)
- return the shallow copy joined with spaces (s.join` `)

Comment: [62 bytes](https://tio.run/##HctLCsMgEADQq4gUomDnBmbdO6QBxU8xnTqSCWmg9Ow2dP/e4nfPYS1tu1aKqWfbDzsewA3L5oSDl29KBVOM13ZUbCcA8LPhqczWycsnfKUzDAuVenKte6DKhAmQHioreUuIJDLhk4WvUbxpxSj1P6jhXoez/AA)

Answer (score 2):

This is my first code golf. hopefully its not shit.

**EDIT: got it down to 54 bytes with a better regular expression.**

**EDIT 2: per suggestions, fixed a bug and made it shorter **

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 46 bytes

```javascript
t=>t.split(' ').map(v=>t.replace(v,'"'+v+'"'))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYtBDsIgEADvvoJwYUmVXk1MPfcRXggFQ11ZApv1@Vi9zGEys3vxPbRc@SLXkZbBy51dr5gZjDLWvX0F@bkWK/oQQc5Gm0mmg9aOeVa@bIpj51Og0gmjQ3pCAr1GRFKJ8NX/zYcabtq6nXIB8yjHfhtf)

Comment: If the input contains duplicate words, subsequent copies never get quoted.

Comment: Splitting on spaces would be shorter.

Comment: @recursive should be fixed.

Comment: @Shaggy thanks, i incorporated your suggestion

Comment: Still doesn't work for duplicate words

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>136</strike> 133 bytes

As C's tokenizing functions would mess up the string on future reads, I instead calculate the number and offsets for each word and then finish when the total number of iterations of the outer loop matches the number of words.

```c
i,j=1;f(s,c,t)char*s,*c,*t;{for(i=0;i++<j;puts(""))for(j=0,c=t=s;t;t=c+!!c)printf("%3$s%.*s%s ",(c=index(t,32))-t,t,"\""+!!(i-++j));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY7BasNADETv@QplqUHalUucHDfbH2l7MGqcyFA3WEoohHz71i7M4c0MAyPtWaRW5bF0eUBjYSe59HM0jsLR82P4mVHLLmtKxzFfb24YAtEaj2XHUrxY9uxF0nYrdJ118gFDc3ix5jVaYxAYpej0dfpF58OeqHV2Dh8hLAvUNqWRKD/rMoTvXidcoZ/PwrBegRgXcyd4bAB0wLV56wj@6f7efVLePGv1ixos6sFP5n8)

Comment: Swapping `"\""+!!(i-++j)` for `i-++j?"":"\""` saves you a byte.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>60</s> <s>40</s> 36 bytes

*-20 bytes inspired by [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/185469/80745)*

```powershell
$args-replace'(\S+) ?','$`"$1" $''
'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZTRTsMgFIbv@xQnJyhr7C58AKOX3uulibLurGtCoAKLmrlnr0DpZqPdLlpCSsv5@PKTFBr9QcZuScqWbeAO9i0TprJLQ40UJfHFy9NNDve84OwN2S0C4zzj7SHLHhYZ@FZ0Q2jckXW8OH1jmEAeJ/LsD77Wu5UkSIOLw2B5V8FxIhWO4CjRgx0wHul5W1vwvdRrqrTcDOKEIo5V40oMwGg1AH3xcgQBtq5UvalLoZz8AqlVRaaA1c6B0g7clro569/9oxSW/o871XTa2iymIBM4k0kADkQ4wTRMhEmEk019IvQinMUUEqEX4SymkAi9CGcxhUSYRDjZ1CfCXjR@cB7JUNQq37VfbECr4ZEICJ5noqX72c8z8TdWeInxFkwInmF6C3rkuMUcvuEK9vGLWWdqVRXA6LOh0tHa39bstasZsjvp/MS1v8QTGSvIFkvbyNolJMdlSe94dODv9dmh/QE)

The result has one extra space and one empty line in the tail.

---

## Powershell, no regexp, 60 bytes

```powershell
($w=-split$args)|%{$p=++$c
"$($w|%{$q='"'*!--$p
"$q$_$q"})"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZRNboMwFIT3nOJ15JTQwBGQuuwBuo8IcQiSZQN2lFYJZ6c2P0lRS7IAC2H8Zt6nsWRTqDOv9JEL0bADxXRp1uwcR7oQuWFJlengurqwIt5sWOqBWdGty9iH//YSRaywxZJtWYk6QN3Unve@9siOsJvc8A3Xxg/va7gC/LYQeH/se3XaCU79ZNpp1N4pmHb0ws046RiMnWE60ucx12SfVO15psRhFMeJmFLbTjjDpOoMg/g8QkI6z2R@yNNEGvFNQsmMVyHtToakMmSOvKtp@21faaL5/3Hnku5bW4TkYAkWIiWEEQgzSONE6EGYTRoSwYKwCMklggVhEZJLBAvCIiSXCD0Is0lDIgyg6YvzwSveYqV9lG2uSMnxlXAWPPa0lO6wP/a0x1jimcdS0FvwwDNQYC23LQZ0pRVd2hXTpsplFhLjXwVPDd/bvzjbdlrF9UkYW3i1P/fe2SroJUQpL3Frxe82r25@AA)

Less golfed:

```powershell
$words=-split $args                     # split by whitespaces
$words|%{
    $position=++$counter
    $array=$words|%{
        $quotation='"'*!--$position     # empty string or quotation char
        "$quotation$_$quotation"
    }
    "$($array)"                         # equivalent to $array-join' '
}
```

Comment: Neither works if the input words contain tabs or other whitespace. From the challenge, only spaces delimit words.

Comment: you are right, of course. But rules are: 1. `The input only contains printable ASCII characters.`, 2. `The input may contain spaces`. Tabs and other whitespace is not printable ASCII, is not it? :)

Comment: I suppose that's true - I was only basing my statement off of the OP's comment [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/185414/as-programmers-say-strive-to-be-lazy/185476?noredirect=1#comment444508_185414), but that hasn't been edited into the challenge ... so I suppose your submission is fine as it currently is.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>14</s> 12 bytes

```
¸£¸hYQ²i1X)¸
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=uKO4aFlRsmkxWCm4&input=IlRoaXMgaXMgY29kZWdvbGYiCi1S)

2 bytes saved thanks to Oliver.

```
¸£¸hYQ²i1X)¸     :Implicit input of string
¸                :Split on spaces
 £               :Map each X at index Y
  ¸              :  Split input on spaces
   hY            :  Set the element at index Y to
     Q           :    Quotation mark
      ²          :    Repeat twice
       i1X       :    Insert X at 0-based index 1
```

Comment: [12 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=uKO4aFlRsmlYMSm4&input=IlRoaXMgaXMgY29kZWdvbGYiCi1S)

Comment: D'oh! Of course! Thanks, @Oliver.

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 104 bytes

```java
t->{var w=t.split(" ");int i=0;for(var s:w){w[i]='"'+s+'"';System.out.println(s.join(" ",w));w[i++]=s;}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY/BboMwDIbvPIXFpWTQaOcyetlll526W9VDmgZqBgmKTVFV8ewsgNZJk5xY8W///lKrm9rWl@8J2855hjq8Zc/YyLK3mtFZ@ZJHkW4UEXwqtPCIALr@3KAGYsUh3RxeoA1acmCPtjqeQPmKxNwJ8O4s9a3xb6u4hxIKmHi7f9yUh6FgSV2DnMQQixwtAxaveel8Msu0G8RjOOKp2MSblNJw54c7sWml61l2wZEbm5CsXVgfLLJBiDwMpOmpoHwcp3yBeIKxIaYAsLIBxF9XJAih3cVUrinj7L@igLCyWKJWYdkdGmcr4zM49wzWMfDVrDXixV4rMn8uH8abxcWGcKHXg7MmXuRxhfv97Dy8WwnFE7CUSmvTcTLXxTowRvMZpx8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Elm](https://elm-lang.org) Using recursion, <s>132,130,121,111,100</s> 99 bytes

Golfed down 9 bytes thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen) technique
and another 22 bytes were cracked by [ASCII-only](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/39244/ascii-only). Turned to non-tail recursion during the golf.

```ml
f b a=case a of
 c::r->String.join" "(b++("\""++c++"\"")::r)::f(b++[c])r
 _->[]
u=f[]<<String.words
```

[Try it online](https://ellie-app.com/5xXSnKStRq3a1)

85 bytes after exposing `String` functions to the current scope

```ml
f b a=case a of
 c::r->join" "(b++("""++c++""")::r)::f(b++[c])r
 _->[]
u=f[]<<words
```

Ungolfed version (Using tail recursion)

```ml
push : List a -> a -> List a
push list el =
    list ++ [ el ]

zip : (List a -> a -> List a -> b) -> List a -> List a -> List b -> List b
zip transform before after mapped =
    case after of
        [] ->
            mapped

        current :: rest ->
            transform before current rest
                |> push mapped
                |> zip transform (push before current) rest

wrap : appendable -> appendable -> appendable
wrap v str =
    v ++ str ++ v

cb : List String -> String -> List String -> String
cb before current rest =
    before ++ wrap "\"" current :: rest
        |> String.join " "

result : List String
result =
    zip cb [] (String.words "This is code golf") []
```

[Try ungolfed](https://ellie-app.com/5xYCtbmYhspa1)

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc) with `/u:System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex` flag, <s>59</s> 40 bytes

```csharp
s=>Replace(s,"(\\S+) ?","$`\"$1\" $'\n")
```

<s>Port of [my Java 8 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/185575/52210), so look there for an explanation.</s>
-19 bytes by porting [*@Arnauld*'s regex](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/185469/52210), since the `` $` ``  and `$'` are supported in C# .NET.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##dYzBSgNBDIbvPkUYFrqLa8Wr2npSeuipLXiZg@OYnQ2MmWWShe3Ld9y2N0UIyc/Hl9/LnRcqbyP7Z9FMHFq43jV0sCqyWu9wiM5jLa2prd3fNvBiWlN9WFM9WAPVwrJpytPNeybFLTHWXW0URU3T/KKHngTm8ekLQ4rd/4YDocDUkXes8QgxccDcwueowElBe7wymfO8vBP827bBjJe2@aXHDIkvUjmlQSmxlPvxcX8Uxe/lASdd7jCM0eXXacgocjbOCKcf)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>70</s> 65 bytes

```powershell
param($a)$a.Split()|%{$a-replace[regex]"( |^)$_( |$)"," ""$_"" "}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY/BasMwDIbvfgoh3BJD2jfYPfcOdhht0DIlMXi2sV3akuTZM7Vhpwmh/0cfv0Ax3DjlkZ1bdQ9vMK2REv1Umoym4yk6Wyoz7yZNh8TRUcefiQe@n7GC@WJ0K6IN1giIukWRZV2UqhRIYeFcsN58w4nBZiAvHcrICYLnP/o@CnpSyHbwtrcd@eIe4IIfONXwdS0gKZDctsviZXSU/93owjcPwfWoDMywg@mF9/Kfbl/2I9nChybkopb1Fw)

Has test suite in trial. Has 1 leading space on first row, and 1 trailing space on last row. Attempting to refactor.

Comment: This doesn't work if you have a duplicate word in the test string.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 19 bytes

```
Ｅ⪪θ ⪫Ｅ⪪θ ⎇⁼κμ⪫""λλ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bUu7CgIxEOz9iiVVAvELrG0EQfBKmzXEy@K6uUv2hPv6GDnsZB4Mw0xIWEJGbu1SSNSecbLXiUnt7MGAcR5OmeRfP8QiWFZ7nBfkap8eXr@1uXUYD@y@ctvDuUNrQ6IKnQiVRqEHBRTlFTjLGIuH@6IgWUFT3Lrac7eANe7a/s0f) Link is to verbose version of code. Note: Trailing space. Explanation:

```
  θ                     Input string
 ⪪                      Split on literal space
Ｅ                       Map over words
       θ                Input string
      ⪪                 Split on literal space
     Ｅ                  Map over words
            μ           Inner index
          ⁼             Equals
           κ            Outer index
         ⎇             If true then
               ""       Literal string `""`
              ⪫         Joined i.e. wrapping
                 λ      Current word
                  λ     Otherwise current word
    ⪫                  Joined with literal space
                        Implicitly print each result on its own line
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 34 bytes

```
Join&sp=>{On&_&Repr=>Iota@_}@Split
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7BCsIwDIbve4owZJftCYTJwIt6UFFvY4zapVuhtKWNBxGfvUbdwk/4@ZI/RBAJOWFSsK7TwWlbRF9vXidb9MUFfag3e0ei6d/N1RtN6Yg4xHblvRy77By0pRtG2oqIsX0ZVfalUe/md8ioRlXQZsCVE2/l1ewnHYEl3YCjM2rhOwz45cKyHE0YwFlcprc5JSDq0WqlpbBknmCcHTFUcH8QcAo492eRPTfJv@VZ16UP) Anonymous function returning a list of lines.

### Explanation

```
Join&sp=>{On&_&Repr=>Iota@_}@Split
                             Split      Splits the input on whitespace
         {         =>Iota@_}            Over each number K, 0 to #words - 1
          On  &Repr                     Apply the Repr (quoting) function
            &_                          on the Kth element in the input
Join&sp=>                               then rejoin the words of each inner sentence
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 46 bytes

```perl6
{map {.prematch~"\"$_\""~.postmatch},m:g/\S+/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJZm@786N7FAoVqvoCg1N7EkOaNOKUZJJT5GSalOryC/uAQsVquTa5WuHxOsrV/735pLrzixUiEtv0ghTUMpJCOzWAGIkvNTUtPzc9KUNK3/AwA)

Comment: The match part can just be `m:g/\S+/`, and I think the pre/post match part can be shorter too

Comment: `/\S/` doesn't match the tab character. I'm actually not sure how whitespace other than space should be treated.

Comment: The question says `printable ASCII`, which only includes spaces, not tabs or newlines

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 123 bytes

I wonder if can this be shortened with regular expressions.

```cs
s=>(r=s.Split(' ')).Select((a,i)=>(string.Join(" ",r.Take(i))+" \""+a+"\" "+string.Join(" ",r.Skip(i+1))).Trim());string[]r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY5BT4QwEIXv/oqXXrYNSOJ5hYtxE43xAsaDeCi1CyOlYFvU9c9js@zFeNhkMpm8efO@Uf5SeVp2s1XXPjiybYq7WzsP2snG6JNWFNg9Pd7ki88L7nKflZOhwDfYCJGV2mgVOJcpibheL7L7kSxnYKnLKtlrTkIkDDVjiUxYHRfJf2PZ08QpuRIxtXI0cCG2q@vl1S3bi2dHQf8F1Jalx984qzryiCXhqbW0JyVtMAeY0bbapWjmADsGhE6vmo9zbEp6zSLylP9AVnNxDibRQOENGnu06EB4Rw@DARYjJnzAwSNgxie@8I0Dfo6M5Rc)

Comment: [118 bytes](https://tio.run/##hY5BS8NAEIXv/orHInSXxqBX666HYkERD1bxkstmu01Wt5Oa3Wii@Ntj2lTEkzAMw5vH@54JJya4ftGQuQixdlQkuL6iZmNrnXt70JTC4vFuLvsg1e8zvddUWH6ahHReNRS5lkpLOcFETM9EurTemshzqcaQ9KZyxBnY4F9uvYt85/yx8TbphFS5lN3lMcvYZ/uVMXbeCiFm/ezoqXbR8j9BGbFkX4uzh9IFDKMRXEFu7Yym6Dv4aihYJ8ibCKoiYmlHLQz3sIwOlu0IY/6tI8vFfzCNHAYrWKxRoITDM17gsQGhwhavqBEQ0eAN72jR4WPP6L8B)

Comment: [110 bytes](https://tio.run/##RY5BS8NAFITv/RVjL9klMXh2uxERPEjxUsVzut0kL8a3dfe1poq/PUaKCMMwzOGbcenSJZpunVDgVZJI3Fa4f368s1Oy1dexjog2lZv9QKK0aUJUxAKyV4ZWsVx7bqUzlOf6JZL4NbFXZ0z5EIhVhqyI5cYP3olSY9FrW9GF7W/G62yZ5WM@u9bafE9m8Turlk8dJcyqkahlasjVLMMJQ@DWxwLbg4CDQDp/7tKcZ3N18kttFv8/9B@yxhYOO3g0aNGB0OMVA97ACNjjHREJggOO@MCIEz5n0vQD "C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler) – Try It Online")

Comment: Port of Java answer - [104](https://tio.run/##RY9BSwMxEIXv/RWPvWzC1uI9piCCBxEvKh6khzRmd0fXSc2kXWvpb19TigjD4zHz@B7j5cILTdc@U@QryYm4W@L2@eHGTmKXh51LSFYWj5uBstKGOIPspWljCs736nQfQYykD@mVVrau6mZsipqXRDncEwd1xi7uIrGqUc@T1qaEm2ZlR3M8TmZ2KlTVU0@CMg5CHVNL3nEe9hgidyHNsd5mcMzIfTjvpPgi3kmotJn9N@o/pMMaHm8IaNGhB@EdHxjwCUbEBl9IEGRssSt/fGOPn0KafgE "C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler) – Try It Online") :)

Comment: @dana [My port is shorter, though ;)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/185600/52210)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen - I saw you got that regex earlier :) Figured that was a totally different approach so I didn't try porting it over, but yeah that is a good solution!

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 bytes

```
⁾""j$€⁹¦K
ḲçⱮL$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R4z4lpSyVR01rHjXuPLTMm@vhjk2Hlz/auM5H5f/h9sj//0MyMosVgChRoSg1EahFISc/L12hODWvJDUvORUA)

Thanks to @JonathanAllan for saving 4 bytes

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to count the `Y` unless you get the OP to allow a list of lines as function output. You can then save 4 [like this](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R4z4lpSyVR01rHjXuPLTMm@vhjk2Hlz/auM5HJfL///8hGZnFCkCUnJ@Smp6fkwYA) (although mine is then just a one Link version of that).

Comment: @JonathanAllan it says a list of lines is ok as output. I’ve added in your improvements - hope that’s ok. Thanks.

Comment: Ah so it does! :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 113 bytes

```
func[s][repeat i length? u: split s" "[j: 1
foreach w u[prin rejoin[t: pick[{"}""]i = j w t sp]j: j + 1]prin lf]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYsxCgIxFET7PcWQVhvbBfEOYhdSxOzP7l9DEpIfRMSzr1EbYRiGeTOFpu1MkzaDHzffotPV6EKZrIARKM6ynNBG1BxYUBWUXkccBp8KWbfgjqZz4YhCa@KoZURmd9NP9VLKMI5Y@6Y/s@m/FTsczHcfvDGbh7osXNHl0kRzCl4NHyydD3/UovIc2bOzUcIDIcWZyh7XJohJIAv9utpzN2crqe0N)

Answer (score 1):

## APL+Win, 59 bytes

```
(⌽⍳⍴s)⊖((¯1 0+⍴s)⍴s)⍪(('"',¨s←(+\' '=s)⊂s←' ',⎕),¨'"')~¨' '
```

Prompts for string

[Try it online! Courtesy of Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlwPWooz3tv8ajnr2Pejc/6t1SrPmoa5qGxqH1hgoG2hA@hFiloaGupK5zaEUxUJuGdoy6grotSHETiA/k6ACN1ARKAxVp1gEpBfX/QKP/p3Gph2RkFisAUaJCcWZ6XmZaZnJiXklOpUJOfl56apGOQlJpiUJefolCSUYqRKwYyAYSyYnFqeoA)

Answer (score 1):

## J, 45 bytes

```
   f =: ' 'joinstring"1(]`(dquote&.>])@.=($~$@=))@cut
   f 'this is a test string'
"this" is a test string
this "is" a test string
this is "a" test string
this is a "test" string
this is a test "string"
```

If the input can be a list of boxes, then my solution can be 30 bytes:

```
   f =: (]`(dquote&.>])@.=($~$@=))@cut
   f 'this is a test'
┌──────┬────┬───┬──────┐
│"this"│is  │a  │test  │
├──────┼────┼───┼──────┤
│this  │"is"│a  │test  │
├──────┼────┼───┼──────┤
│this  │is  │"a"│test  │
├──────┼────┼───┼──────┤
│this  │is  │a  │"test"│
└──────┴────┴───┴──────┘
```

Comment: +1 from me, but I think you need to make it a verb to comply with the PPCG rules:

[Try it online:](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/1RXUs/Iz84pLijLz0pUMNWITNFIKS/NLUtX07GI1HfRsNVTqVBxsNTUdkktL/mtyKXClJmfkK6QpqJdkZBYrAFGiQklqcYkCxAT1/wA)

Comment: Ah I didn't realize that was a rule. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 107 bytes

```python
import re
def f(s):
 for w in re.finditer('[^ ]+',s):p=w.span();print(f'{s[:p[0]]}"{w.group()}"{s[p[1]:]}')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY1BCsIwEADvfcWSSxKUonir@JIQodBNDZhkyW6pUvr2WLwNw8DQV14l31qLiUoVqNhNGCAYtkMHoVRYIeZD9yHmKQpWo90T/Emfj4Iea880ZmPvVGMWE/TGbiB38X5X29rPtSxk7MHsyF394HdtWzCKS0LgMdEbQfAj/5UgS8yzsu0H)

I... decided to use regex against my better judgement. This is the result.

Answer (score 1):

## Oracle SQL, 92 bytes

```
select regexp_replace(s,'(\S+)','"\1"',1,level)from t connect by level<regexp_count(s,' ')+2
```

Assuming there is a table in a form

```
create table t as select 'This is a significantly longer, but not the longest testcase' s from dual;
```

Test in SQL*Plus

```
SQL> select regexp_replace(s,'(\S+)','"\1"',1,level)from t connect by level<regexp_count(s,' ')+2
  2  /

REGEXP_REPLACE(S,'(\S+)','"\1"',1,LEVEL)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
"This" is a significantly longer, but not the longest testcase
This "is" a significantly longer, but not the longest testcase
This is "a" significantly longer, but not the longest testcase
This is a "significantly" longer, but not the longest testcase
This is a significantly "longer," but not the longest testcase
This is a significantly longer, "but" not the longest testcase
This is a significantly longer, but "not" the longest testcase
This is a significantly longer, but not "the" longest testcase
This is a significantly longer, but not the "longest" testcase
This is a significantly longer, but not the longest "testcase"

10 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 93 bytes

```
	S =' '
	I =INPUT S
S	I ARB . R S REM . I	:F(END)
	OUTPUT =L '"' R '"' S I
	L =L R S	:(S)
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/nzNYwVZdQZ2L01PB1tMvIDREIZgrGMhxDHJS0FMIUghWCHL1BbI8Oa3cNFz9XDS5OP1DQ0DqbH0U1JXUgUpAZLCCJxenD0gMqIXTSiNYkwuo@P//kozMYgUgSlQoLinKzEsHAA)

Each line ends with an additional space.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <del>92</del>, 79 bytes

-13 bytes thanks to @Steffan

```python
lambda x:(l:=range(len(x)),[[[x[a],'"%s"'%x[a]][a==i]for a in l]for i in l])[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcZLCsMgEADQq4gQMkIolG5KwFt0N3ExbTQZmKpoFvb09gdv8fLr2FO8XHPpwS5d6HlfSbUZZLaF4uZBfIRmzISIDclNox6qHofvHZK17EIqihRHJb/yvwbPrufC8YAA@rZzVR@PtPotSdCnmoUPMMb0Nw)

Comment: it would be two less bytes if you `yield`ed instead of printing to stdout

Comment: you could actually just use a lambda: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcixCsMgEIDhVzmEkDsoXboVfItu1uGaaHJgVdTBPL1tuhb@4efLR9tTvA2vnyPw@7Uy9Lsxphu2l1lNVc3T@daw1mJ9KsAgEQrHzWFwETvRj@WfRy4SG3pUj10qfFvS6rYUvLrWHKQhEY0P "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcZLCsMgEADQq4gQMkIolG5KwFt0N3ExbTQZmKpoFvb09gdv8fLr2FO8XHPpwS5d6HlfSbUZZLaF4uZBfIRmzISIDclNox6qHofvHZK17EIqihRHJb/yvwbPrufC8YAA@rZzVR@PtPotSdCnmoUPMMb0Nw "Python 3.8 (pre-release) – Try It Online") for 79 bytes with python 3.8

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 108 bytes

```python
def f(s):
 W=s.split();n=len(W)
 for x in range(n*n):print[W[x%n],'"'+W[x%n]+'"'][x%-~n==0]+'\n'*(x%n==n-1),
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Jcm9CsIwGIXhvVfxIUiS/og6tmT3DjLUDgW/2EA5CUmGunjrMSCc4Tm84ZM3j3spL7ZkZVJjQ0anSwq7y1JN0DtDGtWQ9ZEOcqC44s0SLdQYokOezXycsfTiJLo/u8qlavhC62u9T4hW1qI1hpvqi5XiwZHJJVpR5/PGkTxYqKb8AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 134 bytes

```php
<?php $i=explode(' ',file_get_contents('php://stdin'));for($x=0;$x<count($i);$x++){$o=$i;$o[$x]='"'.$i[$x].'"';echo join(' ',$o).'
';}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY1BCsIwEEX3niLIwCRUWtemwYOIFGlTM1IywYwQEM8eo/AW78GHn0KqdTynkBSQ8yVtvHiNCg8rbX66e5lmjuKjZI1tdRqGLAtFNMau/NRQ3NFCGWd@RdFApkXXmTewA7LAFyhXh3vsgX7aN7V@DqweTPH/A2x63KH91CqBsmrclPgsXw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `N`, 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Oı$OṅnṘȧðj
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPU8lQzQlQjElMjRPJUUxJUI5JTg1biVFMSVCOSU5OCVDOCVBNyVDMyVCMGomZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD1UaGlzJTIwaXMlMjBjb2RlZ29sZiZmbGFncz1O)

##### Explanation

```python
Oı$OṅnṘȧðj  # Implicit input
O           # Split it on spaces
 ı          # Map over this list:
  $O        #  Input split on spaces
    ṅ  ȧ    #  Replace the current item with
     nṘ     #  itself surrounded by quotes
        ðj  #  Join this list on spaces
            # Join on newlines
            # Implicit output
```